# Npm command not working in powershell but works in cmd

Tags: node.js, powershell

C:\Users\user>npm --version
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Tried uninstalling and installing node the error persists.. Tried node installing 20,18 these two versions still same..

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect it might be something to do with `PATH` being different between the `cmd` and `ps` environments, so some more debugging might help.

With Command Prompt:

```
echo %PATH%
```

With PowerShell:

```
echo $env:PATH
```